# Where does Yondu of the Ravagers come from?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1, guardians-of-the-galaxy

In Guardians of the Galaxy, one of the main groups are the Ravagers - their leader is the blue-skinned Yondu.

**Where did Yondu come from originally?**

Comment: Interestingly, I can't find a single official source saying that movie-Yondu is Centurion. Lots of articles making the reasonable assumption, but nothing from Marvel, producers, crew, etc.

Comment: Clarification: since you've referenced the Ravagers affiliation, are you asking specifically about the movie version, who is different from the Earth-616 comics version?

Comment: @phantom42 - the movie

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He is most likely Centaurian. His comic book background lists him originating from a tribe on Centauri IV.

In this [interview](http://www.hitfix.com/news/guardians-of-the-galaxys-michael-rooker-on-talking-in-yondus-native-tongue-watch) the reporter asks Michael Rooker if we are going to hear his Centaurian language in the film, and he says "it's possible."

In another [interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qrOvy2E3NYs) the report says `"in the comics Yandu speaks Centaurian, I think it's called, will you be bilingual?"` And Rooker replies by saying `"I will."`

His [Disney Infinity 2.0 profile](http://disneyinfinity.wikia.com/wiki/Yondu) states

> Species: Centaurian
>   Residence: Centauri IV

[image]

Comment: It'd be great if someone could get an in-game screen cap of that bio, because the referenced profile is actually from an unofficial Wikia. If they pulled it from official Disney material, they didn't source it.

Answer (score 4):

Other than the use of the Yaka Arrow (more discussion on that at [What is the weapon that Yondu wields in Guardians of the Galaxy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73326/what-is-the-weapon-that-yondu-wields-in-guardians-of-the-galaxy)), I don't remember the movie making even an oblique reference to Yondu's planet or species.

According to the comics, Yondu is a native of the Earth colony world [Centuri-IV](http://marvel.wikia.com/Centauri-IV):

[image: Yondu's planet of origin]

As [James Sheridan](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79626/where-does-yondu-of-the-ravagers-come-from/79629?noredirect=1#comment167762_79629) points out in comments, it's clear at least that Yondu isn't from an Earth colony world in the MCU. However, that doesn't preclude the possibility that he's still Centaurian, and Centauri-IV just has a different history in the MCU.

Some justification comes from *Agents of SHIELD* season 1 episode 15, "Yes Men." Prompted by Agent Coulson, Lady Sif gives a partial list of blue-skinned aliens, including the Centaurians. It's not proof that Yondu is one, but itat least shows that Centaurians exist in the MCU:

> **Coulson:** You've...visited other realms; seen different...species...aliens. Have you ever...encountered any that were...blue?
>
> **Sif:** Yes, of course.
>
> **Coulson:** Which ones?
>
> **Sif:** Uh, Interdites, Levians, Pheragots, Kree, Sarks, Centaurians; the Frost Giants tried to conquer your Earth a millennia ago.

Comment: In the film, he clearly isn't from a colony of Earth. He looks very similar to the Kree, but not quite the same. The film doesn't state his species or homeworld.

Comment: @JamesSheridan What I find more likely is that he's still from Centauri-IV, but it's not an Earth colony in the MCU. Pure speculation though

Comment: I tend to agree. If they even bother to go into that much detail. I'm more interested in who Starlord's father is, to be honest. Gunn has already revealed that it isn't J'Son.

Comment: Nitpick: Lady Sif lists blue-skinned aliens that exist, but only mentions that the Frost Giants had ever been to Earth, specifically saying that none of the others had (clearly incorrect, as Yondu had been to Earth).

Comment: @phantom42 Corrected

Comment: Just to clarify, does Sif's "Uh" indicate hesitation, or is there a species called the Uh?

Comment: @maguirenumber6 Hesitation and confusion, as I recall. She had somewhat more pressing things on her mind at the time, and didn't understand why Coulson was pushing the "blue aliens" thing