# In Guardians of the Galaxy, if Yondu can’t whistle, can he still use his weapon?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1, guardians-of-the-galaxy

In the movie Guardians of the Galaxy, Yondu whistles when he uses his weapon. What if he can’t whistle? What if his mouth is being taped? Will he still be able to use it?

Comment: According to the [MCU Wiki](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Yaka_Arrow): “Yaka Arrows respond to a specific range of sonic frequencies which change the material's behavior.” The way that’s phrased, it sounds as if there are no other (known) ways to shoot the arrow, short of shooting it, but I don’t know if that’s a reliable source.

Comment: @alexwlchan It's may be possible with mental sonic waves...

Comment: Confusing tags. Your question says film but the tag says comics.

Comment: @Richard If OP is not familiar with the character, they may assume that the weapon also exists in the comics, and that an answer may lie there. Unfortunately, the weapon was created for the movie, so no answer can be found within the main comics (though, there may be something in a movie tie-in)

Comment: @phantom42 - The weapon does kinda exists in the comics; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73326/what-is-the-weapon-that-yondu-wields-in-guardians-of-the-galaxy

Comment: @alexwlchan If it is specifically the frequency that controls the arrow, then Yondu could probably control it by humming, too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### This question cannot be definitively answered. From the director's interview: James Gunn, said in an interview called [Secrets of the Guardians of the Galaxy](http://www.empireonline.com/features/james-gunn-guardians-of-the-galaxy-secrets/p11) in Empire: He controls [his arrow] mostly through whistling...

**Gunn goes on to say:**

> - "Yondu wasn’t in the original script so I put him in the script. Some people say, ‘Oh, you changed him a lot from the comics, so why did you use him?’ And it’s because that’s he has coolest super power ever, and it’s very different from other super powers that exist.
> - **He controls [his arrow] mostly through whistling. There’s a hook-up there between the implant in his brain and his whistling, and that’s how he controls the arrows, through sound. That is what he does in the comics.**"

- Since the device is a homage to the original Yaka arrow, (which COULD be used as just an arrow if Yondu didn't whistle) we are left in the dark as to whether this device can be controlled without the use of sound through the cybernetic implant in Yondu's crest.

Comment: Even when perfectly inert, it's still a pointy stick; he could presumably still stab someone with it. "Every tool is a weapon, if you hold it right."

Comment: I just imagine if the Guardians kidnap him or something, n tape his mouth..Thats why this question popped in my head